# Displaying distinct data from database

Tags: php, mysql, css, html, slideshow

I want PHP code for displaying data from database and I want to add a specific class to first `<li>` .

Below are the statc form of it, but I want it dynamically from my MySQL database.

```
<ul class="photo">
    <li class="first"><a href=""><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li> //only this first line will be giving attribute (class="first")
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="text">
    <li class="first">
        <h2><a href="">Image 1 caption</a></h2>
        <p>Story............</p>
        <a class="next" href="">Next&gt;&gt;</a> 
    </li>

    <li> // this is the caption for the line that will be giving attribute (class="first")
        <h2><a href="">Image 2 caption</a></h2>
        <p>Stories 2.................</p>
        <a class="next" href="">Next&gt;&gt;</a> 
    </li>

    <li>
        <h2><a href="">Image 3 caption</a></h2>
        <p>image 3 story................</p>
        <a class="next" href="">Next&gt;&gt;</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what have u done till now?

Comment: Make your question clear. What can we do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you hava an array of data from the DB:

```
<?php
    $first = true;
    foreach ($array as $item)
    {
        ?>
        <li <?php if ($first) { echo "class='first'"; $first = false; } ?>>
            <h2><?php echo $item["someheader"]; ?></h2>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

This will loop through all the rows from the db, and assign the first class only to the first row in the list.